# How can I call method as a callback?

Tags: c++, driver, wdm

I'm trying to rewrite my driver to the OOP architecture and I'm faced with the problem of calling a method like callback when I don't have any std::XXXX, as well as when arguments to the function itself are passed by a template.

So I have the following class:

```
class Log {
public:
    /*static*/ VOID LogNotifyUsermodeCallback(PKDPC Dpc, PVOID DeferredContext, PVOID SystemArgument1, PVOID SystemArgument2);

    NTSTATUS LogRegisterIrpBasedNotification(PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, PIRP Irp);
    NTSTATUS LogRegisterEventBasedNotification(PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, PIRP Irp);
};
```

Also I have the following code:

```
NTSTATUS Log::LogRegisterIrpBasedNotification(PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, PIRP Irp)
{
//Some line of code....
        KeInitializeDpc(&NotifyRecord->Dpc, // Dpc
            LogNotifyUsermodeCallback, // DeferredRoutine
            NotifyRecord // DeferredContext
        );
//Some line of code....
}
```

DeferredRoutine has the following pattern of calling arguments:

```
VOID Log::LogNotifyUsermodeCallback(PKDPC Dpc, PVOID DeferredContext, PVOID SystemArgument1, PVOID SystemArgument2)
```

I can't call the LogNotifyUsermodeCallback method as static, because arguments are passed there by template, and other methods of the Log class are also called in this method itself, and I don't have other ideas. So, the main question is: how, under all these conditions, can I call LogNotifyUsermodeCallback as a callback method?

Comment: @PaulSanders template as a callback by windows. Check it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nc-wdm-kdeferred_routine

Comment: In a typical callback system you provide a handler function and some sort of identifying information. The system calls your handler function with the identifying information as a parameter. With a class you pass a static member function or a free function that calls the method instead of the method itself and (usually a pointer to) the class instance as the identifying information. The static method casts the identifying information to pointer to the class instance and uses the pointer to invoke the method.

Comment: Here "OOP architecture" is really saying "as a `class`"?

Comment: @user4581301 When I call it as static, I get errors related to accessing other non static members of the class and I have to initialize an object of my class, and this initialization leads me to crash.

Comment: @tadman In this context, yes. And in general, this is only a small part of my project.

Comment: Precisely why it's a two-phase operation. The static function casts the parameter to the correct class and then uses it to invoke the non-static function which can interact with the other non-static members.

Comment: @user4581301 You broke my brain -_-. Do you want me to call a regular function as static, for example like this:

```
static void CallBack(PKDPC Dpc, PVOID DeferredContext, PVOID SystemArgument1, PVOID SystemArgument2)
{

}
```

After that, you want me to initialize a class from static_cast from some arg, but how?! I don't have any extra args for this...

Comment: @user4581301 The identifying information is the last parameter to KeInitializeDpc (which in this case was passed as `NotifyRecord`). The `LogNotifyUsermodeCallback` receives that pointer back as its `DeferredContext` parameter.

Comment: While using a class is generally a good idea, be careful when making C style callbacks as instance methods will lose their binding. You may need to convert pointer arguments back, often using a `static` wrapper function to bridge from C to C++.

Comment: @tadman It seems like a person(@user4581301) has already proposed this idea, but I just don't understand how I can implement this "bridge"

Comment: Here is a simple example of what I'm talking about: https://godbolt.org/z/7GqTT8P3n . Pay attention to Raymond Chen's comment about which parameter needs to be the class instance in your real case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said earlier, arguments are passed to my function by windows itself => I can't let my arguments go there, since they will violate the order of the arguments being passed.

My solution:

I'm creating a C callback + global variable.

```
namespace Cwrapper {
    Log* GLogPtr = nullptr;
    void Callback(PKDPC Dpc, PVOID DeferredContext, PVOID SystemArgument1, PVOID SystemArgument2)
    {
        if (GLogPtr) { return GLogPtr->LogNotifyUsermodeCallback(Dpc, DeferredContext, SystemArgument1, SystemArgument2); }
    }
};
```

Next, I pass the this pointer to my specific class to GLogPtr

```
Cwrapper::GLogPtr = this;
KeInitializeDpc(&NotifyRecord->Dpc, // Dpc
    Cwrapper::Callback, // DeferredRoutine
    NotifyRecord // DeferredContext
);
```

From the information I have read, this method is also called a "trampoline"

Some information: https://web.archive.org/web/20230822094216/https://codeyarns.com/tech/2015-09-01-how-to-register-class-method-as-c-callback.html

Answer (score 0):

Whereas the C++way to register function would be `std::function`, the C way to handle registration is function pointer + userData pointer.

```
// From library
using callBackType = Ret (Arg1, Arg2, void* /* userData */);
void registerCallback(callBackType* f, void* userData);

// Your code
struct Obj
{
    static Ret MyStaticCallBack(Arg1 arg1, Arg2 arg2, void* userData) {
        Obj* self = reinterpret_cast<Obj*>(userData);

        return self->MyMethod(arg1, arg2);
    }
    Ret MyMethod(Arg1 arg1, Arg2 arg2);
};
```

Then you code to register callback would be:

```
Obj my_object;

registerCallback(&Obj::MyStaticCallBack, my_object);
```

Answer (score 0):

SUGGESTION:

1. Define an abstract base class with your "callback method".
2. Define a subclasses for each different implemention of that method.
3. Pass the desired subclass to whatever function or method needs to use it.

EXAMPLE:

```
include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// Define an abstract base class
class LogNotifier {
public:    
    virtual int Register() = 0;
};

// One implementation...
class IrpBasedNotificationLog : public LogNotifier {
public:
    virtual int Register() {
       cout << "Greetings from IrpBasedNotificationLog.Register...\n";
       return 0;
    }
};

// A second, different implementation...
class EventBasedBasedNotificationLog : public LogNotifier {
public:
    virtual int Register() {
       cout << "Greetings from EventBasedBasedNotificationLog .Register...\n";
       return 0;
    }
};

// Invoke the "callback"
void Client(LogNotifier& theLog)
{
  theLog.Register();
}

int main()
{
  EventBasedBasedNotificationLog myLog;
  Client(myLog);
}
```